# Removing duplicates from a large csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a large csv around 24 million rows, and I want to cut in size.

Here is a little preview of a csv:

[image]

I want to remove the rows that have the same CIK and IP, because I have a bunch of these files and they take up a lot of space, so I want to make an efficient way to remove the duplicates.

I've made to test how many duplicates of CIK are there, and for some there are more then 100k, that is why I want to cut those duplicates out.

I've tried some stuff but in most cases it failed, because of the size of the csv.

Comment: What do you mean by *it failed*? does the program crash or you are getting some kind of error?

Comment: How many duplicates do you have per `CIK`/`IP` combination?

Comment: The programs doesn't work I got errors but when I fixed them the program just didn't work, its just loops in infinity, that why i posted so I can get some suggestion on how to do it

Comment: I've made a test script to count how many of the same CIK there are and for some there more then 100k, that is the reason to remove some of them

Comment: are you successfully able to read it into pandas then the drop_duplicates operation breaks? or you can't successfully create a df?

Comment: Can you post what you tried already to see why it loops in infinity?

Comment: I didn't use pandas, but I will try, because it seems to be only suggested solution

Answer (score 6):

Another quick way is to do it with `awk`, running from the command line:

```
awk -F, '!x[$1,$5]++' file.csv > file_uniq.csv
```

where `file.csv` is the name of your file, and `file_uniq.csv` is where you want to have your deduplicated records ($1 and $5 are column numbers, 1 for `ip` and 5 for `cik`)

P.S. You should have `awk` if you're on a Linux/Mac, but may need to download it separately on Windows

Comment: `awk` is definitely a good option, and will almost certainly out-perform pandas.

Comment: Though it is off topic but the brilliant answer and helped to sort my issue

Comment: Thanks for it. I was also processing a large file (more than 4 GB) on a RAM of 32 GB but it was being killed. awk saved me.

Comment: I get an invalid syntax error for this solution :(

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using `pandas` and `reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce

import pandas as pd

df = reduce(
    lambda df_i, df_j: pd.concat([df_i, df_j])
                         .drop_duplicates(subset=["cik", "ip"]),
    pd.read_csv("path/to/csv", chunksize=100000)
)
df.to_csv("path/to/deduplicated/csv")
```

This avoids opening the entire file at once (opening it in 100000 line chunks instead), and dropping duplicates as it goes.

Comment: I think this is a good solution, will try it out, thanks @PMende

Comment: I get this error when trying to run it : "sys:1: DtypeWarning: Columns (14) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False."

Comment: @Stefan If you know the types of all of your columns, you can specify them in the call to `pd.read_csv` (see docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) by passing a `dict` to the `dtype` parameter. For example, you can say something like: `dtypes = {"ip": "str", "date": "str", <other types here>}`. Then in the `read_csv` call, you just add the parameter `dtype=dtypes`. Generally you can ignore the `DtypeWarning`, and pandas does a good job of inferring what types to use.

Comment: Won't this cause an OOM error if the deduplicated file is too big to fit in memory?

Answer (score -5):

You can do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('filepath/filename.csv', sep='your separator', header = True, index=False)
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['cik','ip'], keep=False, inplace=True)
df.to_csv('filepath/new_filename.csv', sep= 'your separator', header=True, index=False)
```

and enjoy your csv without the duplicates.

Comment: I don't know will pandas work, because of the size of the csv